# Sed command using variable in unix sed -n '/15:51:03/,/15:51:10/p'

Tags: variables, sed

`sed -n '/15:51:03/,/15:51:10/p' abc.txt`

I am using above command in my `abc.txt` file to fetch the data between two ranges i.e `15:51:03` to `15:51:10` and it is working fine.

Now I want to pass a variable instead to hard code ranges and following command I'm using.

`sed -n '/$a/,/$b/p' abc.txt`

Could someone tell me why the above code is not working?

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Getting any err-msgs?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to allow the shell to expand the variables:

```
sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" abc.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Hellmar..It is now wroking :)